# Need help installing Google Manage SSL

Tags: google

I am trying to install google managed SSL in my website but I am seeing below error after all setup:

1. SSL certivate status says: Provisioning
2. 

Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Website:
https://www.gears4fitness.com/

Please advice.

Thank you much,
Masuk

Comment: You will need to wait or contact Google for support.

Answer (score 1):

To become ACTIVE, the Google-managed SSL certificate must be associated with a load balancer, specifically the load balancer's target proxy.
At this point, your Google-managed certificate status might still be PROVISIONING. Google Cloud is working with the Certificate Authority to issue the certificate.
Provisioning a Google-managed certificate might take up to 60 minutes.
After that you will have to update the DNS A and AAAA records and Make sure that the records point to the IP address that is associated with the load balancer's forwarding rule or rules
After the certificate and domain statuses are active, it can take up to 30 minutes for your load balancer to begin using your Google-managed SSL certificate.

Step 1. Create a Google-managed SSL certificate

Step 2: Create or update your load balancer

[Step 3: Verify the target proxy association](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#verify-target-proxy)

Step 4: Update the DNS A and AAAA records to point to the load balancer's IP address

Step 5: Test

Please consider that all this process could take more than one hour after saving the changes in every single step